# Grunt: Get current file name in task config

Tags: gruntjs

While configuring my task I want to use current file name the task works on as a template variable in task `options` object. For example in `options['wrap-start']` here:

```
swig_compile: {
  temptarget: {
    options: {
      'wrap-start': 'var <%= CURRENT.FILE.NAME %> = function {', //I want the current file name as function name here 
      'wrap-end': '};'
    },
    files: {
      '<%= config.app %>/scripts/tempcompiled.js': ['<%= config.app %>/templates/*.swig']
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [**grunt-swig-compile** sources](https://github.com/RasterBurn/grunt-swig-compile/blob/master/tasks/swig_compile.js#L50), there is no such feature. `options['wrap-start']` is concatenated to the result as is.

You can fork/copy the **grunt-swig-compile** sources and simply add a replacement of your pattern (e.g. `<%= file_name %>`) with the [`path.basename(filepath)`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_basename_path_ext) in `options['wrap-start']`.